# actionbar.setHideOffset() cause force close

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I used this code for implementing new actionbar using AppCompact v7 and everything was fine:

```
supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mActionbar = getSupportActionBar();
mActionbar.setHideOffset(10);
```

But i had to use xml Toolbar in order to use new animated  navigation drawer indicator.
so this is my new activity_main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainMenu_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/contents"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/content_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Actionbar"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my new code:

```
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.content_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHideOffset(10);
```

And force close occurs at last line.

It doesn't show any errors in logcat , just force close!

Sorry for bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
   getSupportActionBar().setHideOffset(0);
```

> Set the current hide offset of the action bar.
>
> The action bar's current hide offset is the distance that the action
>    bar is currently scrolled offscreen in pixels. The valid range is 0
>    (fully visible) to the action bar's current measured height (fully
>    invisible).

Comment: but i want to use this method to hide action bar smoothly  when content scrolled (on API < 21).